# Tinymce 404 error but file is on the server

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I have a new Wordpress installation which works perfectly on localhost

However, the live version has an issue with TinyMCE

https://toytrainland.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php

Comes up with a 404 error. however, the file is on the server

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be file permission issue, check your files should having 644 permission and all directories have 755 permission.